# Error in NetLogo version 3.1.5 : Nothing named PICKUP-NEAREST-CIRCLE has been defined

Tags: netlogo

i'm a beginner in netlogo and i wanted to make a program where i can drag the turtles wherever i want to (change the place of aturtle by clicking on it and drag it to another place)
here is the code that i have found on youtube but it doesn't work!!
 i got this error "Nothing named PICKUP-NEAREST-CIRCLE has been defined"

```
globals [
previous-button-state
anybody-picked-up?
circle-picked]

to setup
ca
create-turtles 10
ask turtles[
set shape "circle"
set size 3 
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
set anybody-picked-up? false
set previous-button-state "up"
end
to go
if mouse-inside?[
  if mouse-down? and previous-button-state ="up"[
  try-to-pickup-nearest-circle
  ifelse anybody-picked-up?
  [set previous-button-state "down-and-dragging"]
  [set previous-button-state "just down"]  
  ]
  if not mouse-down? [
  set anybody-picked-up? false
 set previous-button-state "up"
  ]
  ]
  ;waite .01
  end 

 to try-to pickup-nearest-circle
let candidate min-one-of turtles [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor]
 ask condidate [
 if distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor < size / 2 [
 set anybody-piced-up? true 
 set circle-picked candidate 
 ]
 ]
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three typos in your `try-to-pickup-nearest-circle` procedure: a missing "-" in the first line, a misspelled "condidate" in the third line, and a misspelled ""piced" in the fifth.  Corrected, it would be

```
to try-to-pickup-nearest-circle
  let candidate min-one-of turtles [distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor]
  ask candidate [
    if distancexy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor < size / 2 [
      set anybody-picked-up? true 
      set circle-picked candidate 
    ]
  ]
```

When NetLogo tells you it can't find something, the first place to look is for a typo.  Also, if you look again at the video at around the 4th minute, you will see that your `go` procedure is missing an `if` block.

```
if mouse-down? and previous-button-state = "down-and-dragging" [
  ask circle-picked [ setxy mouse-xcor mouse-ycor ]
]
```

This is the part of the code that actually moves the circle when it is dragged.  Add that, and you should be okay.

NetLogo 3.5.1 is a very old version.  I'd suggest downloading the latest version.

Comment: thank you so much the code now has no error, but it dosen't function i can't grab the turtles :/   here's the link of the video that i watched it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UGfLenLd12Q   please can you help me if it possible

Comment: I've edited my answer to point out the problem. Good luck with your learning.

Comment: Seconded that nobody should be using NetLogo 3 anymore.